# How to set cell type as string in Apache POI XSSF 4.10?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, cell, xssf

I'm trying to set the cell value as String using Apache POI XSSF 4.10 .

I have used the code

sheet.getRow(i).getCell(k).setCellType(CellType.STRING); but it throws null pointer exception.

Please help

Comment: Ensure that both the row and the cell are defined before using/writing to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have already created the cell in your code, always check if it exists. If you only write to each cell once and you only access them once, the code can be much easier.

Access and write only once (assuming a sheet exists):

```
Row r = sheet.createRow(rownum);
Cell c = r.createCell(column);
c.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

Full code to access cells multiple times:

```
Row r = sheet.getRow(rownum);
if (r == null) {
    r = sheet.createRow(rownum);
}
Cell c = r.getCell(column);
if (c == null) {
    c = r.createCell(column);
}
c.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

Both codes ensure that the cell exists as the `getXYZ` methods can return `NULL` if the specified sheet, row, cell  have not yet been created.

Comment: The function setCellType is deprecated. There is an issue in apache poi that doesnt seem to lock the cell type depending on value. So if you set the value to be a string but it contains numbers, a user editing the document in excel will convert this string to number, making e.g importing same document through apache poi fail since now the cell has changed type.